Restriction map in Borel Moore Homology
Assume $\mathrm{L}\to \mathrm{ M}$ a closed embedding of someth oriented manifold and $M$ is smooth oriented manifold. I wonder if the following diagram commute.
$$
\matrix{
   H^*(\mathrm{M})                 & \to &    H^*(\mathrm{L})               \cr
  \downarrow&                      & \downarrow \cr
  H^{BM}_{m-*}(\mathrm{M})                 & \to & H^{BM}_{l-*}(\mathrm{L})                 \cr
}
$$
Here $H^{BM}_*(X)$ means *-th Borel-Moore homology of $X$, $m$ and $l$ are the dimension of $M$ and $L$ respectively. The upper horizontal arrow is given by pullback along $\mathrm{L}\to \mathrm{M}$ and the lower horizontal arrow is restriction with support map. The vertical arrows stand for Poincaré duality.

How exactly do you define the lower horizontal restriction "restriction" map a priori?

@Thorgott Hi, it’s defined as following: consider embedding $M\to X$, then define $H^{BM}_(M)$ as $H^(X, X-M)$, and the restriction map is given by $X-M \to X-L$. I’m happy if it’s obvious using other(but different) definitions.

I'm confused, restriction is contravariant, so it gives a map $H^{\ast}(X,X-L)\rightarrow H^{\ast}(X,X-M)$, not the other way round. You also forgot that the grading has to be shifted. Generally speaking, Borel-Moore homology is covariantly functorial with respect to proper maps and contravariantly functorial with respect to open embeddings, but I don't believe that pullback along an arbitrary closed embedding exists in general.

@Thorgott I use the “restriction with support” map defined in 2.6.21 of Ginsburg’s book representation theory and complex geometry. Given embedding of oriented smooth manifold $N\to M$, for any closed subset $Z$ of $M$ we have $H^{BM}*(Z)\to H^{BM}{*-(m-n)}(N\cap Z)$, and in particular I choose $Z=M$. Here the degree shift is compatible with Poincaré duality.
